# find max profit from buy/sell on different days

Tags: c++

ok the problem gives you 5 values in an array.  they represent values you buy and sell a stock at. you cant sell until you buy. so the first value is buy. You need to find the max or highest profit you get even if its negative (so -1000 is more profit than -10000). you can assume the appropriate main function and headers are there. the following code is how i solved it:

```
int solution(prices[]) {

int N = 5;  //assumption is can only buy sell for 5 days so prices = [0-4]


int difference;
int max_profit = -100000000000;

for (int p = 0; p < N; p++)
{
    for (int q = p + 1; q < N; q++)
    {
        difference = prices[q] - prices[p];
        if (difference > max_profit)
        {
            max_profit = difference;
        }
    }
}

return max_profit;
```

i want to be able to solve it with out having to include max_proft= -100000000000. bc its possible someone could lose more thant that on on buy and sell.  any thoughts?

Comment: You could use `int max_profit = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();` instead.

Comment: Any thoughts? Use a smaller number. Then think about how small it needs to be to be of any use to you.

Comment: Pull the initial value from the first data set element. `int max_profit = prices[1] - prices[0];` If it isn't usurped later, so be it, if it is, again, so be it, assuming `N >= 2` always.

Comment: Please, note that the value you choose (-100 000 000 000) may be out of range for `int`s in [some environments](https://ideone.com/U2gGjP).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the lowest number possible for `max_profit` initially then use:

```
#include <limits>

//...

int max_profit = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();
```

And if someone has lost more money than that on a stock trade then they have some serious problems ahead...

Comment: haha yeah, i know its highly highly highly imporbable but not impossible, maybe now but in the future who knows. is there away to do `int max_profit = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()` with beginner skills? i just started learning c++

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()` simply returns the smallest value an `int` can hold - i.e. `-2147483648`. There is not much more to using it than simply setting `max_profits` to this value via the above.

Comment: Well, with a 32 bit `int` and a [big crisis](http://blogs.wsj.com/economics/2012/10/01/total-global-losses-from-financial-crisis-15-trillion/)...

Comment: @Bob__ True but losing this amount on a single stock trade is, I hope, virtually impossible ;)

Answer (score 0):

> i want to be able to solve it with out having to include `max_proft= -100000000000`.

Well, you'll need to have a minimum starting value somehow. So what's your concern about it?

The lowest starting value you can get is `std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();`

Comment: im just a beginner and havent learned that yet. any way to do it with beginner skills?